# Error while accessing the image directly using blob URL

Tags: blob, storage, azure-storage

I am new to Azure. I have activated my free subscription to learn Azure. I have created one Storage account in my portal. In that account, I created one container.

I uploaded an image to that container successfully. When I click that image, I have found the URL in properties that I can use to access via browser.

But I am getting below error while performing the above operation.

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:<Guid> Time:2022-05-17T11:20:46.2299517Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

But the image does exist in that container. Why am I getting the above error? How do I avoid that error?

Comment: Please check whether the access level is private. If yes, change it to blob or public to avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks, you are right but where to change that access level? 'Change access level' option is greyed out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment. Please note that, when you are creating a new container, it's access level will be **private by default**.

Please check the access level of your container is **`Private`** or not like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your Storage Account -> Containers -> Your Container "Public access level"***

[image]

If that access level is **`private`**, when you access the blob of that container directly via browser, you will get error like below:

[image]

**To change the access level of your container:**

Select your container that enables **`Change Access level`** Option -> Select Change Access Level -> Select **`Blob`** or **`Container`** from the dropdown -> Click Ok

[image]

Now, access the blob URL directly via browser, there will be no issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, (I was receiving the same error), my container was public (blob), and all the access was set properly.
My problem was that when I uploaded the images using the Azure.Storage.Blobs namespace, for example:

```
`
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobcnnstr, containername);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filefullyqualifiedname)))
{
    containerClient.UploadBlob(filename, stream);
}
`
```

the image uploaded with a wrong CONTENT-TYPE.
For images, content type needs to be "image/jpeg". When image is uploaded using Azure web site, the content type is set automatically to image/jpeg, however, when uploading programmatically, the content type is different (forgot what it was, something...stream). When I would modify the content type for a file manually, the URL started working magically.

So I used the following code to upload the files and set the correct content type.

```
`
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobcnnstr, containername);

BlobClient bc = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filefullyqualifiedname)))
{
    bc.Upload(stream, httpHeaders: new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpeg" }, conditions: null);     
}
`
```

blobcnnstr variable contains the Storage Account Access Key connection string,
containername variable contains container name,
filename variable contains file name without the path,
filefullyqualifiedname variable contains path + filename.

Hope this help someone.